# MongoDB C# driver - how do set a value to max, per $max

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to set a bunch of fields to the Max value between the current value and the new value.

I would think doing

```
UpdateBuilder<ADocument> update = Update<ADocument>

.SetMax (d => d.HighScore, highScore)
.SetMax (d => d.MaxGameTime, gameTime)
.SetMax (d => d.MaxLevels, levels);
```

Etc.. But there is no .SetMax, or no .Max - which would use the $max keyword to set it.

So, how do you do this?  I don't want to create 3 queries (6 in my real example) to query for the Max highScore and set it if .GE, and repeat for each of the other fields.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/MongoCursor.cs#L461-L466

Comment: in 2.6 there is a $max operator for update. Since it's a new operator, you have to be using the latest version of C# driver to be able to use SetMax which @MatijaGrcic correctly pointed you to.

Comment: Looks like the database is 2.4.9 - so I presume that means it isn't supported?  And we are running 1.8.3.9 of the C# driver.  So we need to update to make this work?

Comment: Also, is there a work around, perhaps using a text query though the C# driver?

Answer (score 0):

Support for the $max and $min operators was added to the C# driver in version 1.9.0 of the C# driver. You have to be using at least that version of the C# driver to use the UpdateBuilder to create update specifications that include Max or Min.

The new Update method builders are here:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/v1.x/MongoDB.Driver/Builders/UpdateBuilder.cs#L269

These are not the same as the SetMax and SetMin on cursors, which are a different kind of Max and Min.

The easiest way to gain access to these update operators is to update to the latest version of the C# driver. As a workaround, you could construct the update specification using lower level techniques as follows:

```
var update = new UpdateDocument
{
    { "$max", new BsonDocument
        {
            { "HighScore", highScore },
            { "MaxGameTime", gameTime },
            { "MaxLevels", levels }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: So this will update them only if they are higher than the previous?